# Example $14.18$ out of Lee's Intro to smooth manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined via

$$(u,v) \mapsto (u,v,u^2-v^2)$$

And let $\omega$ be the $2$-form $\omega = y dx \wedge dz + x dy \wedge dz$

Compute the pull back $F^*\omega$. They have

\begin{align}
F^*(y dx \wedge dz + x dy \wedge dz)&= v du \wedge d(u^2-v^2)+udv \wedge d(u^2-v^2)\\
&= v du \wedge (2udu-2vdv)+ udv \wedge (2udu-2vdv).
\end{align}

Does the last line equal to:

$$2uv (du \wedge du) - 2v^2 du \wedge dv +2u^2 (dv \wedge du)-2vu(dv \wedge dv).$$

Is what I have above ^^ correct?

And since $du \wedge du=0$ and $(du \wedge dv)=-(dv \wedge dv)$ this reduces to

$$F^*\omega = -2(u^2+v^2)du \wedge dv.$$

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @ArcticChar sweet, thanks!

Comment: @ArcticChar if I have seen an intro to 3-manifolds and seen an intro to Riemann surface theory, could I skip through the text straight to chapter 12 or 14?

Comment: cause thats what I have been doing, I already have seen tensors in my Rep theory intro course at the masters level.

Comment: I do not know your goal, but why are you skipping everything and read only the part on differential form?